# Sklearn: NotFittedError: This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Soft Voting on Calibration classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I tried to use soft voting on calibration classifiers on sklearn. Since soft voting does not have `prefit` option so far, I tried to make `VotingClassifier.fit()` to call `CalibratedClassifierCV.fit()`. The following is my code:

```
data = load_breast_cancer()

# Data spliting.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target, test_size=0.2)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25)

# Base classifiers.
clf_svm = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, probability=True)
clf_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf_lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs')
clf_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

svm_isotonic = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf_svm, cv='prefit', method='isotonic')
svm_isotonic.fit(X_val, y_val)

lr_isotonic = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf_lr, cv='prefit', method='isotonic')
lr_isotonic.fit(X_val, y_val)

eclf_soft2 = VotingClassifier(estimators=[
    ('svm', svm_isotonic), ('lr', lr_isotonic)], voting ='soft')
eclf_soft2.fit(X_val, y_val)
```

However, I got some strange errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/faceRecognition/faceVerif/util/plot_calibration.py", line 127, in <module>
    main(parse_arguments(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/home/ubuntu/projects/faceRecognition/faceVerif/util/plot_calibration.py", line 120, in main
    eclf_soft2.fit(X_val, y_val)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py", line 189, in fit
    for clf in clfs if clf is not None)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py", line 31, in _parallel_fit_estimator
    estimator.fit(X, y)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 157, in fit
    calibrated_classifier.fit(X, y)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 335, in fit
    df, idx_pos_class = self._preproc(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py", line 290, in _preproc
    df = self.base_estimator.decision_function(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 527, in decision_function
    dec = self._decision_function(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 384, in _decision_function
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 437, in _validate_for_predict
    check_is_fitted(self, 'support_')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 768, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This SVC instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

My question is how to fix this error or is there any alternative solution please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VotingClassifier` will clone the supplied estimators (and their internal estimators as in this case) and then try to fit on them. But in `CalibratedClassifierCV` you use `cv='prefit'` which assumes that you have already fitted the estimators. This leads to conflict and this error.

Explanation:

`VotingClassifier` have two internal estimators

- `('svm', svm_isotonic)`,
- `('lr', lr_isotonic)`

When you call `eclf_soft2.fit`, it will first `clone` the `svm_isotonic` and `lr_isotonic`. Cloning these `CalibratedClassifierCV` estimators will then clone its base estimators `clf_svm` and `clf_lr`.

This cloning happens such that only the parameter values are copied and not the actual attributes learnt from previous calls to `fit()`. So essentially your cloned `clf_svm` and `clf_lr` are unfitted now.

Unfortunately there is no simple way to set this right for your usecase: To fit the votingclassifier, which will in turn fit the internal calibratedClassifiers but not fit the base classifiers.

But if you only want to use the VotingClassifier for its soft-voting capabilities on the combined system of two CalibratedClassifierCV estimators, this can be done easily.

Taking ideas from my other answer on a similar question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42925296/3374996

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

# Define functions
def custom_fit(estimators, X, y):
    for clf in estimators:
        clf.fit(X, y)

def custom_predict(estimators, X, voting = 'soft', weights = None):

    if voting == 'hard':
        pred = np.asarray([clf.predict(X) for clf in estimators]).T
        pred = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:
                                   np.argmax(np.bincount(x, weights=weights)),
                                   axis=1,
                                   arr=pred.astype('int'))
    else:
        pred = np.asarray([clf.predict_proba(X) for clf in estimators])
        pred = np.average(pred, axis=0, weights=weights)
        pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)

    return pred


# Use them
estimators=[svm_isotonic, lr_isotonic]
custom_fit(estimators, X_val, y_val)

custom_predict(estimators, X_test)
```

Comment: I am curious why sklearn doest not provide `prefit` for voting classifiers which could easily solve such problems?

Comment: @Tengerye I was gonna comment that its like this because it interferes with the pipeline architecture of scikit-learn, but found the issue you opened.

Comment: Hi, nice to read from you again. It seems the developers of scikit-learn decided to improve the code but stuck somewhere. BTW, I fixed the bugs from the kind code you provided, would you take a look? @Vivek Kumar

Comment: @Tengerye Thanks for correcting the code. I also slightly modified the `custom_fit()`.